# How to highlight widget title with CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, title, highlight

I'm editing a Wordpress theme I'd like to use for my blog.
I'd like to highlight the titles of the widgets like in this page: http://nathanandaudrey.org/

Ex. http://i.imgbox.com/dh0hApE4.jpg

I tried

```
.widget-title { background: #e1e1e1;}
```

but that changes the color of the entire line and I want to highlight the text, only.
Anybody knows if and how can I achieve the same effect with CSS?
Thanks in advance.

example html;

```
<aside id="recent-posts-2" class="widget widget_recent_entries">
    <h3 class="widget-title">Recent Posts</h3>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: show some html that the widget generates for the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you've not provided any html you're making it harder for answers so this is a bit of a guess.
Use `display: inline-block` on the title element;

```css
.widget {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #666;
}
.widget h3 {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<aside id="recent-posts-2" class="widget widget_recent_entries">
 <h3 class="widget-title">Recent Posts</h3>
 <ul>
  <li>foo bar</li>
 </ul>
</aside>
```

By default div elements are blocks - meaning they span the full width of their containers, if you change it to `display: inline-block` this changes to fit just the content within the div itself.

Comment: I'm very sorry, it's just that I'm not sure what html I should post.
Maybe this?
    <span class="title">Advertisement</span>

I'm going to try what you suggested...

Comment: ideally you should post some example html that either matches or at least resembles the structure of the widget you're trying to manipulate.

Comment: <aside id="recent-posts-2" class="widget widget_recent_entries"> <h3 class="widget-title">Recent Posts</h3> <ul> <li></li> </ul> </aside>

and for the life of me, I can't seem to be able to post the code with the right formatting. I've never felt so stupid in my life.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code.

```
 .widget-title {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I've already tried that but I don't want to fill the entire line with color. Just where the text is.

Comment: Sorry, I hit 'enter' and I submitted the reply by mistake. The code is not working because I don't want to fill the entire line with color. I only want it where the text is.

Comment: Ok, then please try my updated answer. you can change values as you need.

Comment: I adjusted the values and changed them several times. It's a nice effect but I can't turn the shadows into a well-defined box :(